# Upgrade to 5.48.0 seems to cause many CiviMail errors; mailings hanging

Tags: civimail

I'm having strange issues with bulk emails since upgrade to 5.48.0. I'm using the traditional mailer, and not Mosaico. These issues do not appear if the list is small (or maybe it's certain configurations?? Maybe it's the use of variables in the template?).

1. A scheduled mailing does not show in the list. But then I go and flush the cache (cv flush) and it shows up as scheduled.
2. Have to cancel mailing if it hangs. I have now throttled sending to batches of 200, and then it can manage to go, but takes forever.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your CiviCRM Config and Log file that correspond to when the mailing hangs?

Comment: If it works when you limit to 200, you may be hitting memory or processing time limits.

Comment: I did not have this problem before upgrade to the current version, so something is creating a new load on the server. I wondered if it was potential handling of lots of errors/warnings.

Comment: config/error log when failed before batching:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tjKkj8UWS6VFOwAGKKnj3Nnind3jAlX4/view?usp=sharing

config/error log when mailing sent AFTER batching:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XX81BC_9HCI3JpPeq2gqWms7hbBLDW9X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: We have a similar problem. php_error.log writes:

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Cache/SqlGroup.php on line 185

@TimETown did you find a solution for that?

Comment: I was able to increase batches to 250, I think, and then create a cron job in the server to run every five minutes. This is really a work around. I haven't checked status of this during the past few upgrades to see if there problem is now gone.